# Capturing UNIX/ Linux server configuration?

Tags: linux, configuration

I was wondering if there is an existing tool/ set of scripts out there that is designed to capture a snapshot of the configuration for one or more Unix/Linux boxes? Obviously, these are expected to be Linux servers.

The most core needs are:

- capture hardware config (CPU, memory, disks etc)
- capture software config (OS, java, etc)
- easily extensible to help capture details of custom software
- snapshot customization (which details to include/ ignore)
- ability to capture / export snapshot details to machine readable/ parseable formats like JSON/ CSV/ etc

I am already aware of [Puppet facter](https://docs.puppet.com/facter/)  but have set that aside (for now) since it has a hard requirement to have Puppet installed.

My core functional need is to be able to produce a periodically refreshing picture of hard+soft-ware configs across all the boxes from a list.

Perhaps I am searching for the wrong terms (on the lines of "linux capture system configuration")?

Any suggestions or pointers? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`tar caf config.tgz /etc` will do that for you. If that's not what you need, please clarify what you want (your question is rather sparse on detail...)

Also, no, you don't need to install a full puppet to be able to run `facter` -- although you do need ruby.

Comment: Thanks for both your clarifications. I have now added more specifics to my question. I suppose there isn't an existing tool that does this? Since writing my question, I have come across etckeeper. And I stand corrected regarding `facter` :).